# Piping into Start-RSJob

Tags: powershell, poshrsjob

I have a variable defined containing 1000 objects (`$P`) and also have a function that will take pipeline input and add a bunch of stuff to each object in the variable (`Add-Data.AccountDetail`).  Instead of adding the stuff to each thing coming down the pipe one by one I was hoping that PoshRSJob would allow me to split the object being piped in and add stuff to it in parallel.  IE take 5 lots of 200 and then process the adding to each in parallel.

I am not a natural coder but seem to get by, so I'm thankful for your patience and help if this is not clear.

```
$P = Get-PositionalData -AccountName T2000

$P | Start-RSJob -Name AccountDetail -Throttle 5 -ScriptBlock {
 $_ | Add-Data.AccountDetail

}

Get-RSJob | Receive-RSJob
```

I get the following, but nothing seems to be in the `Receive-RSJob`.  I am certainly misunderstanding something fundamental here!

```
Error          : 
Verbose        : 
Debug          : 
Warning        : 
Progress       : 
HasMoreData    : True
HasErrors      : False
Output         : 
RunspacePoolID : fc217600-123f-4d73-9bcc-d1df6f87f6d8
Completed      : False
Batch          : fc217600-123f-4d73-9bcc-d1df6f87f6d8

Name           : AccountDetail
ID             : 169
State          : NotStarted
InputObject    : @{AccounId=T2000}
InstanceID     : 3ba5eeed-d48f-4712-8d32-08f5b12a46a3
Handle         : System.Management.Automation.PowerShellAsyncResult
Runspace       : 
InnerJob       : System.Management.Automation.PowerShell
Finished       : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
Command        : 

                 $_| Add-Data.AccountDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `$P` actually contains when it has 1000 objects, so I can only assume. You only need to tweak your `Start-RSJob` command job a bit.

```
$P | Start-RSJob -Name {$_.AccounId} -Throttle 5 -ScriptBlock {
 $_ | Add-Data.AccountDetail
} -FunctionsToLoad "Add-Data.AccountDetail"
```

The `-Name` parameter is the name of the job. You need to have a new name for each job that you want to run. I replaced your value with `{$_.AccounId}` because I'm assuming that each object in `$P` contains the property AccounId based on your example. You do not have to do it this way, but I'm just providing a way to add some uniqueness to each job. The nice thing about this parameter is that it knows the current pipeline object (`$_`).

You are using a custom function called `Add-Data.AccountDetail`. The scriptblock passed to `Start-RSJob` may not know anything about that function. You can use the `FunctionsToLoad` parameter to load your function. The syntax I have used assumes the function is already loaded in your current scope.

Comment: Appreciate that, thanks.  When I stick a `Wait-RSJob` at the end then this is painfully slow.  I may be putting too much on the function.  My add-data.AccountDetail function builds a buffer of 100 objects and then makes a sql call on 100 at a time, once done there's a final object of 1000 which gets added to $P.    `Get-RSJob | Where-Object  {{State -like "Completed"} -and  {HasMoreData -like "False"} -and {HasErrors -like "False"}  }  | Receive-RSJob ` is empty for a long time!

Comment: It could well be because I am doing lots of small jobs??